# Using multiple lambda functions in pandas .agg() method

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, aggregate-functions

I have this kind of dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({  "values":['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 
                   "category": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                   'dummy': list(range(10))
                  })
```

I can get percentages by group like so:

```
df.groupby(['values', 'category'])['dummy'].nunique().groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: 100 * x / float(x.sum()))
```

I now want to use this approach with`.agg()` like this:

```
aggregators = {'counts': 'count',
              'percentage': lambda z: z.nunique().groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: 100 * x / float(x.sum()))
}

df.groupby(['values', 'category'])['dummy'].agg(aggregators)
```

But I receive this error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'groupby'
```

Seems like `lambda z: z.nunique()` is found to be an integer in this expression.
How can I make my lambda work inside `agg`?
Thanks.